How to "inspect" AccountId20 keys?
Alith has Public Address: 0xf24FF3a9CF04c71Dbc94D0b566f7A27B94566cac and
Private Key: 0x5fb92d6e98884f76de468fa3f6278f8807c48bebc13595d45af5bdc4da702133. Using subkey inspect I could not find a way to arrive at this pubkey from this secret key.
Moreover inspecting this 20 byte pubkey via subkey leads to an error :
subkey inspect --public 0xf24FF3a9CF04c71Dbc94D0b566f7A27B94566cac
Error: Input("Failed to construct public key from given hex")

How should I make this work with subkey and accountId20s?

These are some arbitrary predefined from frontier/polkadot-js. It doesn't really have a URI I think. Subkey doesn't support inspecting such ECDSA keys.

https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/get-started/networks/moonbeam-dev/ If you scroll down enough, you'll find a page where all dev accounts with their URIs are mentioned. I had initially thought they don't have an URI, that they were derived by hashing and truncating Alice, Bob respectively and renamed Alith, Baltathar .. etc. but this table leaves me confused. According to the same, Alith pubkey should be derivable from 0x5fb92d6e98884f76de468fa3f6278f8807c48bebc13595d45af5bdc4da702133

Yep, but I didn't see they were derived from something like //Alith.
